# Rename Command Example With Jedis Client

Tags: redis, jedis

I am using Spring Jedis Client to use Redis in my application. I want to rename the commands so that no one else can fire the same just in case they are able to connect to my server.

Can anyone give an example of how to use rename command from Jedis and then how to fire subsequent commands using the the modified one ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't rename a Redis command yet w/o changing the config file [issue #640](https://code.google.com/p/redis/issues/detail?id=640).

Even if you add the `rename-command` config file directive and restart your Redis, Jedis doesn't seem to allow sending arbitrary commands easily or to provide a trivial (i.e. no code changes) way to rename them.

What you could do, however, if you're really insistent on renaming a command and then calling it from Jedis is EVAL it. This will probably go in my pantheon of ugly hacks (:)) but after adding `rename-command get foo` to my `/etc/redis/redis.conf` and doing `service redis-server restart` look what I can do:

```
$ redis-cli 
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> set bar baz
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> get bar
(error) ERR unknown command 'get'
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> foo bar
"baz"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> eval "return(redis.call('get', KEYS[1]))" 1 bar
(error) ERR Error running script (call to f_db0e060e4f58231d51f21685b20ff847de8ab9e1): Unknown Redis command called from Lua script 
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> eval "return(redis.call('foo', KEYS[1]))" 1 bar
"baz"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Of course, if you take this route your code can get pretty messy in no time at all so be careful where you tread... Good luck!

Comment: Yes, it's as expected. Because rename-command does exactly that - renames a command.
If you want to completely disallow that command to be called against your Redis instance, you should do this in your config:
rename-command get ""

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If a malicious user connects directly to Redis, then one can access all opcodes.</strike>

There is no feature in the Redis library to rename commands. Even if you expose access to a custom API that renames commands, you cannot change the inner opcodes of Redis itself.

#### Edit:

You're right, it is possible to rename commands by changing the config file indeed!

After you set the new command names, you have to recompile Jedis.

First rename the enum on `src/main/java/redis/clients/jedis/Protocol.java`, line 203.

Now find the corresponding enum usage on `src/main/java/redis/clients/jedis/BinaryClient.java` and change it also.

It may be sufficient: everywhere you still keep the old command java interfaces (e.g. zadd etc.), and inside Jedis it will talk to Redis calling the renamed command.

Is that your intention ?

Comment: No but Redis documentation says some commands you can rename commands changing "rename-command" in redis.conf. e.g. rename-command CONFIG b840fc02d524045429941cc15f59e41cb7be6c52